# How to get the 500 status during HTTP request using Jquery file upload plugin

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I Need help on how to trigger 500/404 status. kindly help us, how to handle exception handling using `jquery` file upload plugin.

```
done : function(e, data) {
                                                                                                              alert(data.jqXHR.status);
var errorCode = $.parseJSON(data.jqXHR.responseText).errorCode;
                                         alert("error:::"+errorCode);
                                         alert(`enter code here`"Status"+data.textStatus);
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done is for successful responses, for errors you must use [fail](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/)

This is from the jQuery documentation but the plugin certainly works the same way

```
var menuId = $("ul.nav").first().attr("id");
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: Fail Callback is not triggering in IE 8/9.